# Zabbix Web Scenario Response time Trigger

Tags: web, triggers, zabbix

I am trying to setup trigger for Response Time in Web scenario, the below expression is not working the way it is supposed to be.

```
{server:web.test.time[Intranet,Homepage,resp].last(0)}>10
```

Imagine current response time is 25ms.

The above trigger is suppose to go off since the response time is higher than 10(using 10 for testing). However it is not doing that, but if I change it to <10, trigger will fire which is very weird.

And then I go and increase condition value to 30, the trigger is still ON. To resolve that I have to change the operator back to >10

Could any help me figure out how to setup trigger for Response Time in Web scenario?

Answer (score 1):

That was a silly question! Zabbix was actually getting values in '0.0246' and converting into 'ms'. So for my testing I have created the below trigger and it worked!

```
{server:web.test.time[Intranet,Homepage,resp].last(0)}>0.019
```

Trigger fired off as soon as I updated the trigger! :)